# Complex query with subqueries calculations

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have the following query:

```
    select count(distinct(r.user_id)), p.id_store, u.country, r.price_usd
from receipts as r inner join products as p on p.id=r.product_id inner join customers as c on r.customer_id=c.id inner join users as u on u.id=r.user_id
where month(r.expiration_at)=6
and year(r.expiration_at)=2017
and r.status='trial'
and p.platform not in ('manual')
and c.tester=0
group by 2,3,4
```

This query would show receipts that expire on a particular month. In order to project how much each receipt is worth (please note that we are only taking receipts in trial status) we should multiply by a historical Conversion rate of trial to active. (that is if we had a receipt of 100$ and the expected RR is 50% the receipt would be worth 50$)

With only one query, I would like to add more 2 more columns to the previous query which would be the:

```
'RR' ratio, RR= sum(active) / sum(active + unpaid).
```

Please note status is a column that can have several values ('active, 'unpaid','trial','canceled' and 'pending')

And then, the final step would be to have another column that would be the result of:

```
count(distinct r.user_id) * price_usd * RR
```

I would need this ratio ('RR') to be breakdown by country, and id_store (that is the product name).

To take this RR as normally I do, for the last month data, my query would look like the following:

```
select count(distinct r.user_id), r.status, u.country
from receipts as r inner join users as u on u.id=r.user_id
where month(r.created_at)=5
and year(r.created_ay)=2017
group by 2,3
```

Then I would normally have to take the data into a spreadsheet and calculate the RR with a pivot table.

So this is what I'm expecting to get:

```
Count  id_store          country    price       RR       Expected Revenue
100   trial_subscription  Brazil    10$         50%      500$
200   trial_subscription  France    20$         60%      2.400$
```

This is an example of how receipts table is like:

```
user_id status  price_usd   store_key
1172637 active  89.99   lk3.ios.trial.12m.90
1203314 trial   89.99   lk3.ios.trial.12m.90
1172250 unpaid  89.99   lk3.ios.trial.12m.90
```

The RR would be: count(active) / sum(active + unpaid)

(people who actually paid divided by people who paid plus people who did not pay).

Please bear in mind that I would also like to make a breakdown by the country (which is not directly in receipts table). But you can see the logic in the first query I posted.

**Update**

This is how the query should look like. The problem is that is calculating one RR for each country and not for the each country and product. THANKS @DavidLee for your great contribution.

```
SELECT
   r.count AS count,
   r.id_store AS id_store,
   u.country AS country,
   r.price_usd AS price_usd,
   a.count / (a.count + u.count) AS RR,
   r.price_usd * r.count * (a.count / (a.count + u.count)) AS ExpectedRevenue

FROM
(
   select count(distinct(r.user_id)) AS count, p.id_store, u.country, r.price_usd
   from receipts as r inner join products as p on p.id=r.product_id inner join customers as c on r.customer_id=c.id inner join users as u on u.id=r.user_id
   where month(r.expiration_at)=6
   and year(r.expiration_at)=2017
   and r.status='trial'
   and p.platform not in ('manual')
   and c.tester=0
   group by 2,3,4
) AS r

LEFT JOIN
(
   select count(distinct r.user_id) AS count, r.status, u.country
   from receipts as r inner join users as u on u.id=r.user_id
   where month(r.created_at)=5 AND r.status = 'active'
   and year(r.created_at)=2017
   group by 2,3
) AS a
ON r.country = a.country

LEFT JOIN
(
   select count(distinct r.user_id) AS count, r.status, u.country
   from receipts as r inner join users as u on u.id=r.user_id
   where month(r.created_at)=5 AND r.status = 'unpaid'
   and year(r.created_at)=2017
   group by 2,3
) AS u
ON r.country = u.country
```

Comment: I am having trouble visualizing the output you are expecting from your query.  It would be helpful if you provided sample input data and output data.

Comment: Thanks for replying David.

Comment: What im expecting is the following:

Comment: Count          id_store                                  country   price       RR     Revenue
100              trial_subscription_1 month      Brazil      10$         50%      500$
200             trial_subscription_3month        France    20$         60%    2.400$

Comment: Can you please include that as an edit to your question formatted in some kind of table so I can digest it easier?

Comment: @DavidLee sorry its my first time using stackoverflow. Already added what I would like the expected output to be.  I think the major problem is to add the 'RR' that is a function of a division of the number of 'count' depending on the value of the column status (active , unpaid) and then match it to the correspondent product and country.Please if you have further questions let me know. thanks in advance!

Comment: I see your expected output but I don't see what your inputs would be.  What does your receipts table look like?

Comment: @DavidLee already edited my question. Please let me know if I can make things easier to understand. Thanks again

Comment: I posted an answer, please try it out and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct answer as I am working with limited info, but give this a shot and let me know how it comes out.

I took your RR query and created two RR queries, one for active and one for unpaid.  I then joined this to your base query and calculated out the `RR` and `ExpectedRevenue`.

```
SELECT
    r.count AS count,
    r.id_store AS id_store,
    r.country AS country,
    r.price AS price_usd,
    a.count / (a.count + u.count) AS RR,
    r.count * r.price * (a.count / (a.count + u.count)) AS ExpectedRevenue

FROM
(
    select count(distinct(r.user_id)) AS count, p.id_store, u.country, r.price_usd
    from receipts as r 
        inner join products as p on p.id=r.product_id 
        inner join customers as c on r.customer_id=c.id 
        inner join users as u on u.id=r.user_id
    where month(r.expiration_at)=6
        and year(r.expiration_at)=2017
        and r.status='trial'
        and p.platform not in ('manual')
        and c.tester=0
    group by 2,3,4
) AS r

LEFT JOIN
(
    select count(distinct r.user_id) AS count, u.country, p.id_store
    from receipts as r 
        inner join products as p on p.id=r.product_id
        inner join users as u on u.id=r.user_id
    where month(r.created_at)=5
        and year(r.created_ay)=2017
        AND r.status = "active"
    group by 2,3
) AS a
ON r.country = a.country AND r.id_store = a.id_store

LEFT JOIN
(
    select count(distinct r.user_id) AS count, u.country, p.id_store
    from receipts as r 
        inner join products as p on p.id=r.product_id
        inner join users as u on u.id=r.user_id
    where month(r.created_at)=5 
        and year(r.created_ay)=2017
        AND r.status = "unpaid"
    group by 2,3
) AS u
ON r.country = u.country AND r.id_store = u.id_store
```

EDIT: Fixed Expected Revenue calculation and added product id_store to RR calculation. RR queries are now joined by country and id_store.

Comment: you are a genius!!

Comment: It worked... now I have to check the data and make sure everything makes sense but so far it looks pretty good!! Thank you sooo much! :)

Comment: So actually there is a little bug. Expected revenue is only multiplying RR * price_usd .  I just added what the actual query would look like. However, we are still missing one thing, which is that it only calculates on 'RR' value per country... do you think there is a way we can also narrow it down to country.

Comment: What I mean is that for Brazil for example we have different products but its only showing the same RR (which I guess is calculated on a country basis)

Comment: I updated the answer fixing expected revenue and included id_store for the RR queries.  Please try it again and let me know if any other issues arise.

Comment: Hi David Lee. Many thanks again this is looking really good and its perfect. I have a doubt, now RR is calculated based on country and id_store... if I wanted to calculate RR based on country, id_store and also country (which is a column in user table), i would only need to make another left join with that variable right?

Comment: And, I have two last questions:

Comment: 1) As you may know 'RR' is calculated based on historical data.... For some cases that we have a few data 'RR' could be underestimated/overestimated.... is there a way we can account for that? (like standard deviations or something similar)

Comment: 2) For some countries/products we dont have historical data because the product we are selling is new or we just opened to that market... that's why when this happens I get 'NULL' for RR column (and therefore also for Expected Revenue). Do you know a way to establish a predefined (and fixed value) for those cases??

Comment: Do yo think I could just use 'if' condition to fix these matters?

Comment: 1) I would just use your count column to determine RRs calculated on small population sizes as running standard deviations on small population sizes would not solve that issue.  So basically any count under X is flagged as unreliable expected revenue.

Comment: 2) If you want a predefined fixed value I would just use a CASE statement on your expected revenue field.  This value would be very static and would make it difficult to manage multiple fixed values.  If you wanted multiple fixed values across let say different countries I would create another table and use that.  If you just want one fixed value and need help implementing something like that just let me know.